# If class inherited many times can be slower?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, oop, class

When i try to create good object hierarchy which will help to write less code and avoid to use unnecessary fields ,i feel myself free to create many base classes for good grouping which is usually abstract.
What can be disadvantage of doing it like that ? Many times inherited class can be slower ? 
To see many unnecessary abstract classes which hasn't enough good naming can cause confusing when encounter it in intelli-sense(auto-complete) ? What can be other else ?

Comment: Focusing on a good design, even if there is some inheritance depth, is almost always better than focusing on the performance cost of a good design.

Comment: I think i still didn't get answer as i expected but inheriting many times doesn't cause performance issues.I just understand from responses.

Comment: i will  try to ask another question

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Many times inherited class can be slower?

There's only one way to answer performance questions: try it both ways, and measure the results. Then you'll know.

> What can be disadvantage of doing it like that?

The disadvantage of overly complex object hierarchies are:

1) they are confusing because they represent concepts that are not in the business domain

For example, you might want to have a storage system that can store information about employees, computers and conference rooms. So you have classes StorableObject, Employee, Room, Computer, where Employee, Room and Computer inherit from StorableObject. You mean "StorableObject" to represent something about your *implementation of your database*. Someone naively reading your code would ask "Why is a person a "storable object?"  Surely a Computer is a storable object, and a Room is where it is stored. When you mix up the *mechanisms* of the shared code with the *meaning* of the "is a kind of" relationship in the business domain, things get confusing.

2) you only get one "inheritance pivot" in C#; it's a single inheritance language. When you make a choice to use inheritance for one thing, that means you've chosen to NOT use inheritance for something else. If you make a base class Vehicle, and derived classes MilitaryVehicle and CivilianVehicle, then you have just chosen to *not* have a base class Aircraft, because an aircraft can be either civilian or military.

You've got to choose your inheritance pivot very carefully; you only have one chance to get it right. The more complicated your code sharing mechanism is, the more likely you are to paint yourself into a corner where you're stuck with a bunch of code shared, but cannot use inheritance to represent concepts that you want to model.

There are *lots* of ways to share code without inheritance. Try to save the inheritance mechanism for things that really need it.

Comment: "There's only one way to answer performance questions: try it both ways, and measure the results. Then you'll know." Well actually it would be helpful if you could tell us if there is any *possibility* of a performance difference. Is inheriting from a base class identically the same performance wise as copy-pasting the base class code into a new class, and avoiding inheritance? Or does the compiler follow a pointer to the base class object, costing us a little?

Comment: @Olhovsky: I don't know what performance metric is relevant to you. Small changes to code can change layouts in memory, which can cause changes in processor cache locality, which can cause big differences in performance, for some people's definition of "big". How are you going to know that if you don't try it?

Comment: My question is whether the compiler will do anything differently if I inherit a field from a base class or just create the field in a new class instead. I have a question and explained it more clearly, so that you might get some rep for answering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907310/performance-considerations-of-inheritance-in-c

Answer (score 5):

I have just made a very simple practical test (unscientific though) where I created empty classes named A, B, C ... Q, where B inherited from A, C from B and so on to Q inheriting from P.

When attempting to retrieve some metrics on this I created some loops in which I simply created x number of A object, x number of B objects and so on.

These classes where empty and contained only the default constructor.

Based on this I could see that if it took 1 second (scaled) to create an object of type A then it took 7-8 seconds to create an object of type Q.

So the answer must be YES a too deep hierarchy will impact performance. If it is noticable depends on many things though, and how many objects you are creating.

Comment: I believe the test is off, though, considering the OPs concern. Of course Q, which inherits a ton, would take longer than A which inherits nothing. The real question would be, if one class had all the property definitions, and another class inherited to aggregate all the property definitions, would they perform the same?

Answer (score 4):

Consider composition over inheritance, but I don't think you'll experience performance issues with this.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're doing reflection, or something like that where your code has to walk the inheritance tree at runtime, you shouldn't see any speed differences, no matter how many levels of inheritance a class has, or no matter how many classes implement your particular class.

The biggest drawback is going to be making your code unnecessarily brittle.

If class B is implementing/inheriting A just because B is going to need similar fields, you will find yourself in a world of hurt six months later when you decide that they need to behave differently from A to B.  To that regard, I'll echo k_b in suggesting you'll want to look at the Composition pattern.